# D3 circle packing is not working in angular9

Tags: d3.js, angular9

How to integrate D3.js in angular 8?
I tried multiple ways but I am not able to develop a circle packing diagram.
Anyone can help me and share the same example in stackblitz

Example demo: https://observablehq.com/@d3/circle-packing  or https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-circle-packing

Comment: Please post a code sample of what you have so far or what error you have, i.e. codesandbox.io allows you to run an Angular app

Comment: Hi @GuillermoGarcia,
I am facing a problem with the importing of d3.js in angular 9. 
Both the links contain only JS code and when I am using d3.min.js by using https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3 dependency that time D3 code is not working (No error in the console)

Answer (score 0):

I created a codesanbdox in order to show you how I use D3 in Angular, here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-leaf-1evjk

I import the library this way `import * as d3 from "d3";`

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution for d3 circle packing in angular 9.
we need to use below syntax to use d3 for different types of diagrams.

declare  var d3;